# Fudge mocking datetime.now

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to use mock library, to replace result of `datetime.now()` to test some logic. So I'm using now `mocker` and it works good, but i got some problems, perhaps bugs, so I want to move on something more updated. Google suggest to use `fudge` so... I can't let it mock `datetime.now()`

```
from one import ClassName
def test_fudge():
    import fudge

    @fudge.patch('datetime.datetime.now')
    def a(dtn):
        dtn.expects_call().returns(1)
        print 'fudge:', 'yep' if ClassName().one() == 1 else 'nope'
    a()
test_fudge()
```

one.py file:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
class ClassName(object):
    def one(self):
        return datetime.now()
```

result: `fudge: nope`

Any ideas?

**Mocker example**:

```
import mocker
from one import ClassName
m = mocker.Mocker()
n = m.replace('datetime.datetime')
n.now()
m.result(123)
with m:
    print ClassName().one()
```

**one.py** is same.
Result: 123

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the way that you have imported the `datetime` module in *one.py*.  Instead, try this:

```
import datetime
class ClassName(object):
    def one(self):
        return datetime.datetime.now()
```

This is an issue that arises due to the way that Python imports work.  You would have had the same issue had you used a different mocking library such as `mock`.

I'll try to explain but there are better answers somewhere in StackOverflow, I couldn't find the one I was after.

When `from datetime import datetime` is used, the `datetime` package is imported and the `datetime.datetime` class reference is bound in the local scope of *one.py*.

The name that fudge has been given to override however is `datetime.datetime.now()`, which is a different name to the local binding on *one.py*, so no patching occurs.

Put another way, when `test_fudge()` runs and it is looking to patch the name `datetime.datetime.now`, how does it know that the the `datetime` name in *one.py* refers to the same object as `datetime.datetime` at run time?

Comment: Thank you, but similar code works perfectly with `mocker`. Maybe some dirty magic? I'll try this idea later, I'm sorry.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you please add an example that works to your question for comparison.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the way `mocker` works, but it appears to have the same problem. ie. if your *one.py* contains an `import datetime` as shown in my answer, then the `mocker` test case will fail.